# R: performance issues when computing mutual information matrix with NAs

Tags: r, performance, nested-loops, mutual-information

I realized that computing mutual information on a dataframe with `NA` using R's `infotheo` package does not yield errors but incorrect results. The problem is described in more detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578915/mutual-information-larger-than-smaller-one-of-both-entropies/579018#579018) but while I now have a mathematically correct solution which only removes pairwise incomplete cases instead of across all columns the performance for large data sets it catastrophic. I guess it is the nested for loop which causes the long compute times, does anyone have an idea how to improve performance of the below code?

```
library(infotheo)

v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
v2 <- c(1,NA,3,NA,5,NA,7,NA,9,NA)
v3 <- c(NA,2,3,NA,NA,6,7,NA,7,NA)
v4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,7,8,9,10)
df <- cbind.data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)

ColPairMap<-function(df){
t <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df)))
colnames(t) <- colnames(df)
rownames(t) <- colnames(df)
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
               for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
                                c(1:ncol(df))
                                if (nrow(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),])>0) {
                                    t[j,i] <- natstobits(mutinformation(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),j], df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),i]))
                                } else {
                                    t[j,i] <- 0
                                }
               }
}
return(t)
}


ColPairMap(df)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tweak which is not helping for toy data sets as `df` above but for real world data sets, especially when executed on some proper H/W I've seen examples where it reduces a 2.5hrs compute time to 14min!
The code below is a complete copy&pastable exmple which incorporates Rui's solution using a nested `for` loop and building on this idea another solution using a nested 'foreach' loop parallelizing the task on 75% of the available cores.
You can control the size of the data set and consequently the compute time by adjusting n.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(infotheo)

n <- 500 #creates an nXn matrix, the larger the more compute time is required
df <- (discretize(matrix(rnorm(4*n*n,n,n/10),ncol=n)))

## pairwise complete mutual information via nested for loop ##
start_for <- Sys.time()
ColPairMap<-function(df){
t <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df)))
colnames(t) <- colnames(df)
rownames(t) <- colnames(df)
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
               for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
                                c(1:ncol(df))
                                if (nrow(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),])>0) {
                                    t[j,i] <- natstobits(mutinformation(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),j], df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),i]))
                                } else {
                                    t[j,i] <- 0
                                }
               }
}
return(t)
}
ColPairMap(df)
end_for <- Sys.time()
end_for-start_for


## pairwise complete mutual information via nested foreach loop ##
start_foreach <- Sys.time()
ncl <- max(2,floor(detectCores()*0.75)) #number of cores
clst <- makeCluster(n=ncl,type="TERR") #create cluster
#e <- new.env() #new environment to export libraries to cores
#e$libs <- .libPaths()
#clusterExport(clst, "libs", envir=e) #export required packages to all cores
#clusterEvalQ(clst, .libPaths(libs)) #export required packages to all cores
clusterEvalQ(clst, { #export required packages to all cores
    library(infotheo)
})
registerDoParallel(cl = clst) #register cluster

t <- foreach (j=1:ncol(df), .combine="c") %:% #parallellized nested loop for computing normalized pairwise complete MI between all columns
        foreach (i=j:ncol(df), .combine="c", .packages="infotheo") %dopar% {
            combine="c"
            compl_cases <- complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)])
            if (sum(compl_cases) > 0) {
                natstobits(mutinformation(df[compl_cases,][,j], df[compl_cases,][,i]))
            } else {
                0
            }
        }

RCA_MI_Matrix <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df), dimnames = list(colnames(df), colnames(df))) #set-up empty matrix for MI values
RCA_MI_Matrix[lower.tri(RCA_MI_Matrix, diag=TRUE)] <- t #fill lower triangle with MI values from nested loop
RCA_MI_Matrix[upper.tri(RCA_MI_Matrix)] <- t(RCA_MI_Matrix)[upper.tri(RCA_MI_Matrix)] #mirror lower triangle of matrix into upper one
end_foreach <- Sys.time()
end_foreach-start_foreach

stopCluster(cl=clst) #stop cluster
```

Answer (score 1):

Twice the speed.

```
ColPairMap2 <- function(df){
  t <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df),
              dimnames = list(colnames(df), colnames(df)))
  df <- as.matrix(df)
  for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    for (i in j:ncol(df)) {
      compl_cases <- complete.cases(df[, c(i, j)])
      if (sum(compl_cases) > 0) {
        t[j,i] <- natstobits(mutinformation(df[compl_cases, j], 
                                            df[compl_cases, i]))
      }
    }
  }
  lt <- lower.tri(t)
  t[lt] <- t[lt] + t(t)[lt]
  t
}

all(ColPairMap(df) == ColPairMap2(df))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Test the speed.

```
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = ColPairMap(df),
  f2 = ColPairMap2(df)
)
print(mb, order = "median", unit = "relative")
#Unit: relative
# expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   f2 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100  a 
#   f1 2.035973 2.01852 1.907398 2.008894 2.108486 0.569771   100   b
```

Comment: Thanks, Rui! In fact with larger data sets and a less sophisticated benchmark (`system.time`) it is getting closer to 5 X the speed :-)
I still feel I'm missing something though. Comparing it against a simple `natstobits(mutinformation(df))` w/o any looping I'm getting this on a larger df:
> system.time(MI_Matrix <- natstobits(mutinformation(df)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.010 
> system.time(MI_Matrix1 <- ColPairMap1(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  16.49    0.20   17.78 
> system.time(MI_Matrix2 <- ColPairMap2(df))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.28    0.00    3.27

Comment: My gut feeling is that it is not the `complete.cases` which is causing this 300X slow down but the for loop. Any idea how to avoid that?